# How to insert modal tag in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I have a set of delete file in my datatable below, the script is working as user to click `delete` to perform delete function. Now my plan is to insert a modal prior to perform a delete function, but I don't know where to put the modal in jQuery dataTable.

jQuery dataTable

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({   
columns: [
            {"data": "filename"},
            {"data": "timestamp"},
            {"data": "uploader"},
            {"data" : "filename",
                render: function (data) {
                    return "<span title='view' onclick='view_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'><img src='images/view_file.png'></span><span title='delete' onclick='delete_file(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'><img src='images/bin.png'></span>";     
            }}
        ],
});
```

Modal

```
<data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmation-upload">
```

Comment: i think you have to add an `id` on your `delete` span that corresponds to the `data-target` of your modal

Comment: my problem is solved by put the datatables in function delete.